# How do I generate a Snort pcap file?

Tags: ubuntu, wireshark, pcap, snort

I am new to using snort and still learning in university. I am wondering after I find an intrusion how can I log it and save it as a pcap file? What would the syntax look like to do this? So I can analyze it further with Wireshark. I am doing what the guy is doing in the video below with two virtual machines. This is for an at home lab. Here is the video,

https://youtu.be/iBsGSsbDMyw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is `cd /var/log/snort` for the file path. Once you have this you can open `Wireshark` and just follow this file path and open the pcap files.